# Looking for an efficient Alternative for "intersect" function in matlab 2015

Tags: matlab

i have a program in MATLAB 2015 that calls `intersect` function more than 5 million times. for example:

```
x=[2,4,6,3]
y=[3,5,7,9,1,6,4]
tic;for i=1:5*1e6;t=intersect(x,y);end;toc;
*Elapsed time is 365.038992 seconds in my computer
```

but because of the `intersect` function my program is too slow, is there any efficient alternative for `intersect` function? builtin or Mex or something like these. I also tried `unique(x(ismember(x,y)))`:

```
tic;for i=1:5*1e6;t=unique(x(ismember(x,y)));end;toc;
*Elapsed time is 227.7381 seconds in my computer
```

although this cause some improvements but this is not enough!
i have the same problem with `unique()` and `ismember()` too.

Comment: if `x` and `y` are static then you can safely pull `intersect` out of the loop.

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to 2015b to take advantage of the new [faster execution engine](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/)?

Comment: 5 million function calls are always slow and Matlab is slower than the most of them. I am not sure if `parfor` will be much better either since Matlab then needs to set up 5 million workers. My best guess is that you should create a function to which calculates the intersection for a range of values. Then you use `parfeval` to evaluate the function over a range (for example, the first worker from 1-100,000, second from 100,001-200,000, and so on: you can choose values which suit your needs). Also, see if you can improve performance by using column vectors.

Comment: You should post a better example, because now you're intersecting the same vector a million times. We need a more adequate dataset. Most important question would be: as the resulting vectors of intersect have different lengths, how should they be stored? I assume you're directly using the result of intersect within your loop, so we need to know the subsequent function as well.

Comment: Thank for Quick Response. this is just an example to show how much slow the function is.-Question Edited!

Comment: This is not sufficient. We probably can't replace intersect with the information you provide, as intersect is the dedicated function to do what you want. But maybe we can speed up the whole context.

Comment: @RezaSh A quick calculation of what time each loop took resulted in 0.045 ms per iteration. I would not say it is very bad. The alternatives I can see is either parallelization or reducing the number of iterations. That said, note that you have a lot of checks in `unique()` and `ismember()`. You could try to take the necessary parts of the functions and write a new function doing only these parts. This will not provide any guarantees, but in case of speed you do not want it. These are however minor optimizations. You should also run the profiler to see how much time is used by `subsref()`.

Comment: @patrik how do i parallelize the iterations? my program in a heavy multi objective optimization, and has a lot of `for` loops, can i run some part in parallel (or some kind of multithreading)in my PC? Haw can i do that?

Comment: @RezaSh Matlab have limited functionality for this. I would recommend to use `parfeval` for short jobs, since parfor would set up too many workers. You do not always want one worker per loop. You would typically want each worker do a few iterations. Note that you still only can run about 5, 10, 20, ... workers at the same time. Search for **Parallel compution toolbox**.

Comment: If the example is indicative of your *exact* use-case, you could try `sort(y(any(bsxfun(@eq,x(:),y(:).')))).`

Comment: @TroyHaskin Thanks it was very good. Although i am still looking for more efficient way.

Comment: @RezaSh Define your criteria you used to assess why Troy's code is "inefficient" compared to what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast solution that works in all cases (elements can be non-unique and/or non-positive).

```
tmp = sort(x(ismembc(x,sort(y))));
t = tmp([~~diff(tmp),true]);
```

Basic idea behind it is the same as in your suggestion with `unique(x(ismember(x,y)))`, however both `ismember` and `unique` are slow and can be improved. We can use built-in `ismembc` instead of `ismember`, but we need to ensure second argument is sorted. And instead of using `unique`, we use a combination of `sort`, `diff` and logical indexing.

That gives an improvement of **~15.5x** over `intersect` on Matlab 2013b:

```
>> tic; for i=1:1e5, tmp=sort(x(ismembc(x,sort(y)))); t = tmp([~~diff(tmp),true]); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.998081 seconds.

>> tic; for i=1:1e5, t = intersect(x,y); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 15.538410 seconds.
```

For a more specific case, if you know that elements of `x` are unique, you can just use the result of `ismembc` straight away, resulting in **~33x** speedup:

```
>> tic; for i=1:1e5, t = x(ismembc(x,sort(y))); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.465070 seconds.
```

Benchmark results could obviously differ on another Matlab release and/or PC, but I believe the outcome would be the same regardless.